# Right way to implement operator overloading for mixed-mode arithmetic in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Let's say I have some user-defined type T which is expected to support mixed-mode arithmetic such as T + 2, 15 + T and T + T.

I can define operator + to accept operands of different types:

```
T operator+(T a, T b) {
    return a += b;  // assume that operator += is implemented as a member function of T
}

T operator+(T a, int b) {
    // implementation
}

T operator+(int a, T b) {
    // implementation
}
```

In case type T is expected to support arithmetic operations with many other types (int, double, string etc.) number of combinations of T and those types and their positions (T, string / string, T) will be quite high.

My question is if there is more elegant way to overload operators to reduce the number of such combinations.

Comment: You can get away with only implementing the `T operator+(const T&, const T&)` function, and ensuring that you have appropriate constructors for `T` that take the other types you want to be able to add. The compiler is allowed up to one conversion per parameter when finding a function, and those constructors will provide it. This could get hairy if you have types `G` and `H` though, and you want one notion of adding them together to create a new `G`, and another notion to create a new `H`. So be careful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe it's the easiest way since I have appropriate constructors for creating T from int and string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use case.

Many time you can get away with writing a constructor for

```
T(int i) {
    //construct T from int
};
```

and not mark it as explicit. Now you can do T + 2, 15 + T and T + T by just defining

```
T operator+(T a, T b)
```

since implicit conversion will kick in an convert your `int` to a `T`. If you need many different arithmetic types you can many times get away with making one template constructor.

```
template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<U>, int> = 0>
T(U u) {
    //construct T from arithmetic type
};
```

Now the same `operator+` will take care of all the built in numbers.

Another option can be to give `T` a conversion operator to `int`, but since you are asking about `operator+` that returns `T` I'll skip that example. Principle is the same but you would get `int`s after adding.

If your `T` is very complex, sometimes you will just need to give it a lot of different operator overloads.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually, type T represents really big number which is stored as string in this type. T can be constructed from int or string and I need to implement all comparison and arithmetic operators, it's not just about +. But I suppose that approach with using constructors not marked as explicit will be sufficient in this case.